# Using Tunnelier to execute command line ssh

Tags: svn, ssh

I have taught myself to use tortoise for svn changes but after "committing" the changes I was still relying on others to "push" the ssh so the changes reflect live on the server... I downloaded [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) but dont quite know where to start to run that command line update

---

am using puTTY at the moment to do the command line "svn update" if there is a better solution would love to hear it

Comment: can you be more elaborate. Where are you pushing, why ssh ?

Comment: updating the tortoise svn "commits" i was told that's the only way to get the changes reflected on the production server

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for an automatic update/upload mechanism which runs after you committed your changes to the svn server, then you should look for [svn hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks), especially the `post-commit` hook.

Comment: i looked into it more and im using putty for now... but ill look into hooks, thanks!